# Data Driven Framework - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: frameworks, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

I am automating a web application testing using Selenium Webdriver(Java with JUnit) and I am quite familiar with Data Driven Testing. Now I want to build a Data Driven framework and I don't have any resources to start with.

Does anybody have idea how I could start with building framework and what are all the initial setup I need to make.?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. !!

Comment: What is your Data Driven Model?? Using Excel??

Comment: By the way I googled data driven testing with Selenium and found some really helpful blogs. May be you should have a look.

Comment: As mentioned in question I know Data Driven Testing (using Excel), but I wanted to know about creating Data Driven Framework using Selenium. Even googling wasn't much helpful. I just wanted to know what are the initial setup needed.

Comment: Well If you are aware of DDT, you wont find Selenium to be any different. It's basically depends on your logic. You just need an Excel handler and rest is Selenium/JUnit coding. I will suggest to create APIs for the most used functions and you are ready to go.

Comment: Many Thanks !! I'm already using Selenium/JUnit with Excel handler for DDT but I wasn't aware of creating API's. It would be very helpful, if you know, if you recommend any websites/books to follow to start building API's for most used functions.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Get start google with TestNG or JUnit then [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)  and  [PageObject](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Excel utility for Read and Write data in Excel sheet, Going forward you can manage it through Selenium.

Reference Link:

https://www.guru99.com/data-driven-testing.html

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/data-driven-framework-selenium-apache-poi/

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/